# Read/Parse JSON with Java

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I've got a JSON object from the following YAHOO url, which will give me back a stock ticker symbol using a query. The URL is.

```
    http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=Siemens&callback=YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback
```

When I'm using an online json validator it seems, that the JSON object returned by YAHOO is not 100% valid.

The site

```
http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
```

told me, that the JSON object is invalid. So I've decided to use a substring of the YAHOO webservice, which is a valid JSON object. In this case I'm using the output

```
{"ResultSet":{"Query":"siemens","Result":[{"symbol":"SI", ... }]}}
```

With this substring all my validators told me, that I've got a valid JSON object here.

My Java code, where I'm trying to deserialize my JSON object with looks like this:

```
import java.util.List;

public class ResultSet {
private String query;
private List<Result> result;

public String getQuery() {
    return this.query;
}

public void setQuery(String query) {
    this.query = query;
}

public List<Result> getResult() {
    return this.result;
}

public void setResult(List<Result> result) {
    this.result = result;
}
}

public class Result {
private String exch;
private String exchDisp;
private String name;
private String symbol;
private String type;
private String typeDisp;

public String getExch() {
    return this.exch;
}

public void setExch(String exch) {
    this.exch = exch;
}

public String getExchDisp() {
    return this.exchDisp;
}

public void setExchDisp(String exchDisp) {
    this.exchDisp = exchDisp;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSymbol() {
    return this.symbol;
}

public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
    this.symbol = symbol;
}

public String getType() {
    return this.type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getTypeDisp() {
    return this.typeDisp;
}

public void setTypeDisp(String typeDisp) {
    this.typeDisp = typeDisp;
}
}
```

My code, where I'm trying to deserialize the object with GSON from Google looks like this.

```
public String getTickerSymbol() {
    String content = new URLContentLoader(url).getContent();
    content = content.substring(43, content.length()-1);

    ResultSet data = new Gson().fromJson(content, ResultSet.class);

    System.out.println(">>" + data.getResult());

    return null;
}
```

The content of the variable named "content" is

```
{"ResultSet":{"Query":"siemens","Result":[{"symbol":"SI","name": "Siemens AG","exch": "NYQ","type": "S","exchDisp":"NYSE","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"SIE.DE","name": "Siemens AG","exch": "GER","type": "S","exchDisp":"XETRA","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"SIE.MU","name": "SIEMENS N","exch": "MUN","type": "S","exchDisp":"Munich","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"SIEMENS.NS","name": "Siemens Ltd.","exch": "NSI","type": "S","exchDisp":"NSE","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"SIE.MI","name": "Siemens AG","exch": "MIL","type": "S","exchDisp":"Milan","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"SIE.F","name": "SIEMENS N","exch": "FRA","type": "S","exchDisp":"Frankfurt","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"SIEMENS.BO","name": "Siemens Ltd.","exch": "BSE","type": "S","exchDisp":"Bombay","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"SIEB.SG","name": "SIEMENS SP.ADR","exch": "STU","type": "S","exchDisp":"Stuttgart","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"SIEB.DE","name": "Siemens AG","exch": "GER","type": "S","exchDisp":"XETRA","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"SIE.L","name": "Siemens AG","exch": "LSE","type": "S","exchDisp":"London","typeDisp":"Equity"}]}}
```

The function call data.getResult() gives back the value "null". The output of the function getTickerSymbol prints out the following console output.

```
>>null
```

Anybody knows why the object is not deserialized in the right way?

My goal is to use the YAHOO webservice to retrieve the ticker symbol for a company to receive their stock quotes.

**SOLUTION**

The main problem was the capitalization. **Q** uery was written with capitalized Q. In the class ResultSet it was written with **q** . The data binding mechanism is not able to handle this out of the box. With jackson you can use Annotations, so that you do not have to modify the JSON-Object and the original variable names. In Java it is not a commond code style to use capitalized variable names. With the Jackson Annotions you can do the mapping manually. It works!

With the following code I got it to work. Thanks for your advices :-)

**Solution with Jackson lib**

```
import java.util.List;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

public class ResultSet {
private String query;
private List<Result> result;

public String getQuery() {
    return this.query;
}

@JsonProperty("Query")
public void setQuery(String query) {
    this.query = query;
}

public List<Result> getResult() {
    return this.result;
}

@JsonProperty("Result")
public void setResult(List<Result> result) {
    this.result = result;
}
}
```

**Code for Helper class**

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class JsonUtils {
public static <T> T parseJson(String json, Class<T> resultType) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        return objectMapper.readValue(json, resultType);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

**Building the object**

```
ResultSet rs = JsonUtils.parseJson(content, ResultSet.class);

for ( Result result : rs.getResult() ) {
    System.out.println(result.getSymbol());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because ResultSet.class doesn't really correspond to the given JSON. Unfortunately you need to have another class that would be a container for ResultSet:

```
public class JsonContainer {

  private ResultSet jsonContainer;

  // getter/setter
}
```

then you would need to do this:

```
JsonContainer data = new Gson().fromJson(content, JsonContainer.class);
```

If this doesn't work than you have to play with camel case: change `private ResultSet jsonContainer;` to `private ResultSet JsonContainer;` or use `@SerializedName`.

Comment: I've read this hint in another stackoverflow thread. Unfortunately this didn't helped me :-/ Any other suggestion?

Comment: It was due to capitalization problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there is no property named ResultSet inside the ResultSet class. You should deserialize this substring:

```
{"Query":"siemens","Result":[{"symbol":"SI","name": "Siemens AG","exch": "NYQ","type": "S","exchDisp":"NYSE","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"SIE.DE","name": "Siemens AG","exch": "GER","type": "S","exchDisp":"XETRA","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"SIE.MU","name": "SIEMENS N","exch": "MUN","type": "S","exchDisp":"Munich","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"SIEMENS.NS","name": "Siemens Ltd.","exch": "NSI","type": "S","exchDisp":"NSE","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"SIE.MI","name": "Siemens AG","exch": "MIL","type": "S","exchDisp":"Milan","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"SIE.F","name": "SIEMENS N","exch": "FRA","type": "S","exchDisp":"Frankfurt","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"SIEMENS.BO","name": "Siemens Ltd.","exch": "BSE","type": "S","exchDisp":"Bombay","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"SIEB.SG","name": "SIEMENS SP.ADR","exch": "STU","type": "S","exchDisp":"Stuttgart","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"SIEB.DE","name": "Siemens AG","exch": "GER","type": "S","exchDisp":"XETRA","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"SIE.L","name": "Siemens AG","exch": "LSE","type": "S","exchDisp":"London","typeDisp":"Equity"}]}
```

Comment: I don't understand. There are two classes ResultSet.class and Result.class - I've generated those classes using http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com/ Anyway, I've also tried your suggestions to only parse the Result Array. For this I've shortened the JSON object like in your example. Still no luck. When I want to retrieve values using my get-methods I always get "null" back. The debugger also didn't helped me :-/

Comment: @Marting: As I understand the answer you need one more level of nesting: The class you provide to `fromJson` has to "contain" a `ResultSet` class.

Comment: @nikow: Thanks for the advice. I've created a class named JsonContainer with the member variable jsonContainer of type ResultSet and added setters/getters. Then I've called JsonContainer data = new Gson().fromJson(content, JsonContainer.class); Unfortunately data.getJsonContainer() is still null. What I'm doing wrong? I've also used the JSON fragment which was posted by hakyer

Comment: It was due to capitalization problem.